# FFmpeg WebM AV1 Support

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, webm

With FFmpeg how can I use `AV1` codec in a `webm` container?

I get the error:

```
Only VP8 or VP9 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

---

However Wikipedia says WebM supports AV1.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AV1

`AV1 is intended to be able to be used together with the audio format Opus in a future version of the WebM container format for HTML5 web video`

Or can FFmpeg simply not encode this new version?

---

My settings:

```
ffmpeg -y 

-i "C:\Users\Matt\video.mp4" 

-c:v libaom-av1 -strict experimental 
-cpu-used 1 -crf 28 
-pix_fmt yuv420p 
-map 0:v:0? -map_chapters -1 
-sn 

-c:a libopus 
-map 0:a:0? 

-map_metadata 0 

-f webm 

-threads 0 

"C:\Users\Matt\video.webm"
```

Comment: If you're open to using tools other than `ffmpeg`, you can try [`mkvmerge`](https://mkvtoolnix.download/) ([which I hear has experimental support for AV1 in MKV/WebM](https://mkvtoolnix.download/doc/NEWS.md)). But as I mention in my answer, the bitstream for AV1 in MKV/WebM hasn't been finalized yet, so the files you create today might be invalid tomorrow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ffmpeg currently doesn't support muxing AV1 in WebM. [The error you're getting comes from this code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/de1b44c20604c05812ad70167a26d45e0ec1526f/libavformat/matroskaenc.c#L1297-L1305):

```
if (mkv->mode == MODE_WEBM && !(par->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_VP8 ||
                                par->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_VP9 ||
                                par->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_OPUS ||
                                par->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_VORBIS ||
                                par->codec_id == AV_CODEC_ID_WEBVTT)) {
    av_log(s, AV_LOG_ERROR,
           "Only VP8 or VP9 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM.\n");
    return AVERROR(EINVAL);
}
```

Note the lack of [`AV_CODEC_ID_AV1`](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/1a31c2b5df1179fdc1b8e84c8fa89d853e517309/libavcodec/avcodec.h#L442) in the expression.

This isn't too surprising, though. AV1 in Matroska (and therefore WebM) hasn't been finalized yet. If you want to follow progress on AV1 in Matroska (and WebM), [follow the discussion here on the IETF CELLAR mailing list](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/msg/cellar/oAxbYWJcZx4t5XvuIUp8AW8F8EQ).

Answer (score 3):

Update, `FFmpeg` does support AV1 in Webm now!

```
        if (!native_id) {
        av_log(s, AV_LOG_ERROR,
               "Only VP8 or VP9 or AV1 video and Vorbis or Opus audio and WebVTT subtitles are supported for WebM.\n");
        return AVERROR(EINVAL);
    }
```

Source code [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/matroskaenc.c#L1662).